# Reportbuilder showing the same like WPF

Tags: wpf, unicode, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

So I'm programming and I want to show my first name and last name but i want my last name on a new line. Of course I use the function \n right after my first name. In WPF it shows it like how it should be shown:

```
first name
last name
```

If I now want to show this through a report with SSRS this will not work cause my report will show `first name \n last name`. Is there anyway that report builder will understand this function and give me the same representation like in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will ever understand "\n". Instead of "\n", use "vbcrlf" - that sticks in a carriage return and drops the text to a new line.

You can just encase the field with your text with the below:

```
=Replace(Fields!<<fieldname>>.Value, "\n", vbcrlf)
```

Make sure the text is not set to interpret tags as HTML and you'll be fine.